# OpenCL read_imagei returning wrong values

Tags: c#, image-processing, opencl

I have recently started using openCL.Net and have run into an issue with some image processing code. What I am trying to do is target specific colors in an image and change them to a different RGB values, in order to reduce the total number of colors in the image. The workflow for this process goes as follows:

- Identify all colors in an image.
- Identify a color to remove.
- Round that color to the next nearest color in the image.
- Find all pixels in image that match that color and change them to the rounded color.
- Repeat above steps until number of colors threshold is met.

I have all of this code functioning in C#, but now I want the pixel changing done on the gpu since running through 250000 pixels multiple times in a row can take a couple of minutes.

```
using OpenCL.Net;
private Context _context;
private Device _device;

   public void SetupOpenCL()
    {
        ErrorCode error;
        Platform[] platforms = Cl.GetPlatformIDs(out error);
        List<Device> devicesList = new List<Device>();

        CheckErr(error, "Cl.GetPlatformIDs");

        foreach (Platform platform in platforms)
        {
            string platformName = Cl.GetPlatformInfo(platform, PlatformInfo.Name, out error).ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Platform: " + platformName);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.GetPlatformInfo");
            //We will be looking only for GPU devices
            foreach (Device device in Cl.GetDeviceIDs(platform, DeviceType.Gpu, out error))
            {
                CheckErr(error, "Cl.GetDeviceIDs");
                //Console.WriteLine("Device: " + device.ToString());
                devicesList.Add(device);
            }
        }

        if (devicesList.Count <= 0)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("No devices found.");
            //Set bool used to signify that code processed on CPU only
            return;
        }

        _device = devicesList[0];

        if (Cl.GetDeviceInfo(_device, DeviceInfo.ImageSupport, out error).CastTo<Bool>() == Bool.False)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("No image support.");
            //Set bool used to signify that code processed on CPU only
            return;
        }
        _context = Cl.CreateContext(null, 1, new[] { _device }, ContextNotify, IntPtr.Zero, out error);    //Second parameter is amount of devices
        CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateContext");
    }
```

Through Visual Studio, I can see that my computer has a Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz and a Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400 (GPU). The code that sets up my kernel is as follows:

```
public Bitmap ImagingTest2(Bitmap inputBM, int[] oldRGB, int[] newRGB)
    {
        ErrorCode error;
        //Load and compile kernel source code.
        string programPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\ImagingTest2.cl";
        //The path to the source file may vary

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(programPath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Program doesn't exist at path " + programPath);
            return inputBM;
        }

        string programSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(programPath);

        using (OpenCL.Net.Program program = Cl.CreateProgramWithSource(_context, 1, new[] { programSource }, null, out error))
        {
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateProgramWithSource");
            //Compile kernel source
            error = Cl.BuildProgram(program, 1, new[] { _device }, string.Empty, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.BuildProgram");
            //Check for any compilation errors
            if (Cl.GetProgramBuildInfo(program, _device, ProgramBuildInfo.Status, out error).CastTo<BuildStatus>()
                != BuildStatus.Success)
            {
                CheckErr(error, "Cl.GetProgramBuildInfo");
                Console.WriteLine("Cl.GetProgramBuildInfo != Success");
                Console.WriteLine(Cl.GetProgramBuildInfo(program, _device, ProgramBuildInfo.Log, out error));
                return inputBM;
            }
            //Create the required kernel (entry function)
            Kernel kernel = Cl.CreateKernel(program, "imagingTest", out error);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateKernel");

            int intPtrSize = 0;
            intPtrSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
            //Image's RGBA data converted to an unmanaged[] array
            byte[] inputByteArray;
            //OpenCL memory buffer that will keep our image's byte[] data.
            Mem inputImage2DBuffer;
            OpenCL.Net.ImageFormat clImageFormat = new OpenCL.Net.ImageFormat(ChannelOrder.RGBA, ChannelType.Unsigned_Int8);
            int inputImgWidth, inputImgHeight;

            int inputImgBytesSize;
            int inputImgStride;
            inputImgWidth = inputBM.Width;
            inputImgHeight = inputBM.Height;
            //Get raw pixel data of the bitmap
            //The format should match the format of clImageFormat
            BitmapData bitmapData = inputBM.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, inputBM.Width, inputBM.Height),
                          ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);//inputImage.PixelFormat);
            inputImgStride = bitmapData.Stride;
            inputImgBytesSize = bitmapData.Stride * bitmapData.Height;

            //Copy the raw bitmap data to an unmanaged byte[] array
            inputByteArray = new byte[inputImgBytesSize];
            Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, inputByteArray, 0, inputImgBytesSize);
            //Allocate OpenCL image memory buffer
            inputImage2DBuffer = (Mem)Cl.CreateImage2D(_context, MemFlags.CopyHostPtr | MemFlags.ReadOnly, clImageFormat,
                                                (IntPtr)bitmapData.Width, (IntPtr)bitmapData.Height,
                                                (IntPtr)0, inputByteArray, out error);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateImage2D input");

            //Unmanaged output image's raw RGBA byte[] array
            byte[] outputByteArray = new byte[inputImgBytesSize];
            //Allocate OpenCL image memory buffer
            Mem outputImage2DBuffer = (Mem)Cl.CreateImage2D(_context, MemFlags.CopyHostPtr |
                MemFlags.WriteOnly, clImageFormat, (IntPtr)inputImgWidth,
                (IntPtr)inputImgHeight, (IntPtr)0, outputByteArray, out error);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateImage2D output");
            //Pass the memory buffers to our kernel function
            error = Cl.SetKernelArg(kernel, 0, (IntPtr)intPtrSize, inputImage2DBuffer);
            error |= Cl.SetKernelArg(kernel, 1, (IntPtr)intPtrSize, outputImage2DBuffer);
            error = Cl.SetKernelArg(kernel, 2, (IntPtr)(sizeof(int) * 4), oldRGB);
            error = Cl.SetKernelArg(kernel, 3, (IntPtr)(sizeof(int) * 4), newRGB);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.SetKernelArg");

            //Create a command queue, where all of the commands for execution will be added
            CommandQueue cmdQueue = Cl.CreateCommandQueue(_context, _device, (CommandQueueProperties)0, out error);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.CreateCommandQueue");
            Event clevent;
            //Copy input image from the host to the GPU.
            IntPtr[] originPtr = new IntPtr[] { (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0 };    //x, y, z
            IntPtr[] regionPtr = new IntPtr[] { (IntPtr)inputImgWidth, (IntPtr)inputImgHeight, (IntPtr)1 };    //x, y, z
            IntPtr[] workGroupSizePtr = new IntPtr[] { (IntPtr)inputImgWidth, (IntPtr)inputImgHeight, (IntPtr)1 };
            error = Cl.EnqueueWriteImage(cmdQueue, inputImage2DBuffer, Bool.True,
               originPtr, regionPtr, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, inputByteArray, 0, null, out clevent);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.EnqueueWriteImage");
            //Execute our kernel (OpenCL code)
            error = Cl.EnqueueNDRangeKernel(cmdQueue, kernel, 2, null, workGroupSizePtr, null, 0, null, out clevent);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.EnqueueNDRangeKernel");
            //Wait for completion of all calculations on the GPU.
            error = Cl.Finish(cmdQueue);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.Finish");
            //Read the processed image from GPU to raw RGBA data byte[] array
            error = Cl.EnqueueReadImage(cmdQueue, outputImage2DBuffer, Bool.True, originPtr, regionPtr,
                                        (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0, outputByteArray, 0, null, out clevent);
            CheckErr(error, "Cl.clEnqueueReadImage");
            //Clean up memory
            Cl.ReleaseKernel(kernel);
            Cl.ReleaseCommandQueue(cmdQueue);

            Cl.ReleaseMemObject(inputImage2DBuffer);
            Cl.ReleaseMemObject(outputImage2DBuffer);
            //Get a pointer to our unmanaged output byte[] array
            GCHandle pinnedOutputArray = GCHandle.Alloc(outputByteArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            IntPtr outputBmpPointer = pinnedOutputArray.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            //Create a new bitmap with processed data and save it to a file.
            Bitmap outputBitmap = new Bitmap(inputImgWidth, inputImgHeight,
                  inputImgStride, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, outputBmpPointer);
            inputBM.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
            pinnedOutputArray.Free();
            return outputBitmap;
        }
    }
```

Where inputBM is a known Bitmap that I have the RGB data for every pixel. oldRGB is the RGB values of the pixels that I want to change. newRGB is the RGB values that I want to change the pixels to.

Finally, here is the code for the kernel itself:

```
__kernel void imagingTest(__read_only  image2d_t srcImg,__write_only image2d_t dstImg, int4 oldRGB, int4 newRGB)
{
  const sampler_t smp = CLK_NORMALIZED_COORDS_FALSE | //Natural coordinates
  CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP_TO_EDGE |
  CLK_FILTER_NEAREST;

  int2 coord = (int2)(get_global_id(0), get_global_id(1));
  int4 bgra = read_imagei(srcImg, smp, coord); //The byte order is BGRA
  //printf("%v4i\n", bgra); //For Debug only

  if(oldRGB.x == bgra.z && oldRGB.y == bgra.y && oldRGB.z == bgra.x)
  {
    bgra.x = (int) newRGB.z;
    bgra.y = (int) newRGB.y;
    bgra.z = (int) newRGB.x;
    bgra.w = 255;
  }
  write_imagei(dstImg, coord, bgra);
}
```

I can compile and execute this code successfully. The problem is that the image returned from the gpu is very different colorwise. Using the printf command, I found that the RGB values I get for my input image are different in C# when I use Bitmap.GetPixel from when I use read_imagei within the kernel. He is what I got during one of my tests.

RGB values from Bitmap containing 6 colors using Bitmap.GetPixel:

- 255,52,12
- 226,105,123
- 255,206,206
- 246,167,180
- 250,250,250
- 255,213,213

Same Bitmap passed to the gpu returns the following RGB values with read_imagei:

- 255,0,0
- 255,192,192
- 255,120,120
- 255,160,160
- 255,255,255
- 255,220,220

I'm not sure if this difference is being cause by a image formatting issue or possibly by some sort of rounding that the gpu is performing during the read_imagei command. I'm a self taught programmer and I have hit the limits of my googling capabilities. Any explanation for or help with this problem would be appreciated.

Thanks,

******** **Update** ********

So I ran another test with an image that had a few more colors. When I read the pixels in C# using Bitmap.GetPixel, I found 10 unique colors. When I read the image on the gpu using read_imagei, it returned 17 unique colors. I have no idea why there is this difference in the number of colors.

RGB values from Bitmap containing 10 colors using Bitmap.GetPixel:

- 217,0,40
- 250,133,0
- 255,157,37
- 254,231,61
- 7,113,26
- 28,136,23
- 1,110,165
- 121,54,102
- 96,78,135
- 247,111,1

Same Bitmap passed to the gpu returns the following RGB values with read_imagei:

- 228,3,3
- 255,140,0
- 247,111,1
- 255,237,0
- 255,137,0
- 255,173,0
- 255,241,0
- 255,240,0
- 0,118,40
- 0,128,38
- 0,77,255
- 0,75,255
- 0,130,0
- 0,94,205
- 121,0,127
- 117,7,135
- 56,61,222

Comment: It almost feels like an RGB vs. sRGB gamma conversion. More samples would help determine if it is that. Also, why `read_imagei` instead of `read_imageui`?

Comment: @Dithermaster When I was using read_imageui, the values that were being returned ranged from 122-377. I wasn't sure why and using read_imagei seemed to be returning the correct values. I was going to try to solve this color issue first and then go back and figure out what was going on with the read_imageui later.